# JSF Datatable duplication header

Tags: jsf, datatable, jasper-reports

I'm new of JSF, i'm trying to create a datatable but have a problem with this!
This is my code:

JSF file (Datatable):

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{hsinfo.tableContent}" var="o"
                styleClass="table"
                headerClass="table-header"
                rowClasses="table-odd-row,table-even-row">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">SBD</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{o.sbd}"></h:outputText>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Họ Tên</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value = "#{o.ten}"></h:outputText>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Ngày Sinh</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value = "#{o.ngaysinh}"></h:outputText>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Giới Tính</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value = "#{o.gioitinh}"></h:outputText>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

I don't know why if i just use `#{o.sbd}`, the code have error, but if i use `<h:outputText value="#{o.sbd}">`, the header row is not appeared and the column name duplicated each row like this :

[image]

Comment: I don't know why if i just use #{o.sbd}, the code have error, but if i use  <h:outputText value="#{o.sbd}"> , the header row is not appeared and the column name duplicated each row like this :

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /timhs.jsp (line: 67, column: 10) #{...} is not allowed in template text"

The line that i put #{o.sbd} is 67

Comment: I guess here that you are having problems with the strange characters like `Giới Tính`, try to encoding with this site: http://native2ascii.net/ write this text there on the left panel then click on the right arrow do this for all texts you have on your jsp page.

Comment: Is this a datatable in jasperreport? JSF by itself can not do this